# smallest unsigned int that can contain the positive values of a given signed integral?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, integral

Can the smallest unsigned int that can contain the positive values of a given signed integral type be determined at compile time?

So the smallest unsigned integral type that is large enough to hold the max value of a given signed integral type.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned

Comment: It depends what you mean by "smallest", since some of the integer types can have the same size. For example, consider a system in which `int` and `long` have the same size and range of values. Is the answer to your question for`long` `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or is either fine?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is that 2 is the base-number and we need to take into account the 2-based logarithm. General rules:

1. If an unsigned integer has a `sizeof` n bytes, then the largest positive number is (2^(8 * n)) - 1
2. If a signed integer has a `sizeof` n bytes, then the largest positive number is (2^(8 * n - 1)) - 1

As a result, you need to determine the `sizeof` a variable of the given type and see if it has a sign.

Comment: Every signed type has a corresponding unsigned type; and that type is defined to be able to store all of the signed type's non-negative values, so none of this is necessary.

Comment: I believe it is both fun and useful to know the actual mechanics and formulae.

Comment: I'd revisit your math.